# How to convert stereo audio files to mono?

Tags: r, pam, raven

I have multiple stereo .wav recordings which I want to convert into mono files for further analysis. Is there a way in RavenPro/R/Audacity to batch convert them to mono sound files (channel 1 or channel 2)?

Comment: What is special to "further analysis" that inhibits you to read stereo but process selected channel?

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about reading and processing stereo audio files directly (for example, creating annotations in one channel in a stereo audio file as a training data for a ML model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the tuneR package in R. The function will map across all your stereo recordings and extract audio from the 1st channel in the listed directory

```
library(tuneR)
library(purrr)
```

List all stereo .wav files that needs to be converted

```
file_paths <- list.files("E:/test", pattern = "\\.wav$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Creating a function to extract left (channel 1) from a stereo audio file and save it in the working directory

```
extract_channel1 <- function(file_path) {
  audio <- readWave(file_path)
  channel_1 <- channel(audio, "left")
  writeWave(channel_1, paste0("mono_", basename(file_path)))
}
```

Applying the function to each file path in the list using purrr

```
map(file_paths, ~ extract_channel1(.))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way to batch convert them in R - almost certainly yes; Audacity - probably; Raven Pro - not that I'm aware of, but possibly.

However, I tend to use the free open-source program SoX (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) for this task with a little bit of shell scripting.

There are entire StackExchange sites dedicated to this sort of shell scripting, and I almost certainly adapted code from one of these. I'll leave searching for that as an exercise for the reader and I won't attempt to duplicate here.

Instead, I will post the recipe and script that I use to do this on the windows command line.

1. Install [SoX](https://(https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/))
2. Add SoX installation to windows path
3. Create a windows batch file (e.g. named splitStereo.bat) with the following content:

> ```
> for %%n in (*.wav) do (
> sox %%n -c 1 %%n_left.wav remix 1
> sox %%n -c 2 %%n_right.wav remix 2)
> PAUSE
> ```

4. Place stereo wav files to split in a folder with this batch file.
5. Run the batch file from the file manager.

This script will batch convert all wav files in a folder splitting channel 1 into files with the suffix with _left.wav and channel 2 into files with the suffix '_right.wav'.

Comment: Scripting is OK, but in my windows11 system the cmd.exe does not work/exist anymore and all is replaced by Powershell and WindowsTerminal (only a sidenote).

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. I think I figured out a way using the tuneR package in R

Comment: Glad you found a solution indobatrachus. Would be great if you could post as an answer here.

@WMXZ: I'm still on Windows 10, and surprised to hear that there's no cmd.exe. According to this link https://www.minitool.com/news/open-command-prompt-windows-11.html, it looks like cmd.exe still exists on Windows 11, it's just a little harder to find.